# compile kotlin source in application

Tags: android, kotlin

Does Kotlin  compiler provide any api that I can use to compile file or preferably string to bytecode. I want to use that api in android Kotlin application itself.So I'm in the situation that I can't use CLI.

I have tried using `K2JVMCompiler` but that crashes as it tries to access to `javax` to display output.(`'javax'` not supported in android)
I would like to communicate with compiler using Standard I/Os.

Comment: Kotlin has a scripting API. Last I tried, it did not work on Android, in part because it uses the same compiler. Also note that your app might be banned from the Play Store or other distribution channels, depending on where the Kotlin source is coming from and what you are doing with it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Idk why K2jvmcompiler tries to access that javax.swing